# Reference request: probabilistic models on climate (change)

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, applied-mathematics, mathematical-modeling

I am looking for probabilistic models to address climate change. Are they known in the existing literature?

I have found the post [Math behind climate modeling.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/285220/math-behind-climate-modeling) concerning PDE models.

Many thanks for the suggested references!

Answer (score 2):

Here are some pointers to the literature:

- [The
  use of the multi-model ensemble in probabilistic climate
  projections](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsta.2007.2076)
- [Physics-guided probabilistic modeling of extreme precipitation under climate change](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41598-020-67088-1)
- [Probabilistic climate change predictions applying Bayesian model averaging](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsta.2007.2070)
- [Challenges in using probabilistic climate change information for impact assessments](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rsta.2007.2080)
- [Whose Probabilities? Predicting Climate Change with Ensembles of Models](https://www.journals.uchicago.edu/doi/pdf/10.1086/656815)
- [Stochastic Information in the Assessment of Climate Change](https://d-nb.info/975745441/34)

Comment: Thank you very kindly for sharing the references